# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'ErneGaels'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am reading table data from my SQL Server database and getting an error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'ErneGaels' 
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2hwn.png)

I am using a string value `TeamN` for my `Session["TeamName"]` value in my SQL query, however it's not working.

(The `Session["TeamName"]` is `ErneGaels` as that is the team that is logged in)

Whenever I hard code the value of the team name eg 'ErneGaels' in the SQL query it works perfectly and I get the result I need.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

sqlcon.Open();
string TeamN = (string)Session["TeamName"];

SqlDataReader myReader = null;

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Registeration WHERE TeamName = " + TeamN, sqlcon);

myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (myReader.Read())
{
    lblID123.Text = "" + (myReader["TeamID"].ToString());
    lblName.Text = "" + (myReader["TeamName"].ToString());
    lblCounty.Text = "" + (myReader["County"].ToString());
    lblEmail.Text = "" + (myReader["Email"].ToString());
    lblPassword.Text = "" + (myReader["Password"].ToString());

    Session["TeamID"] = lblID123.Text.Trim();
}

sqlcon.Close();
```

I want to be able to return the 'TeamID' value so that I can assign it to a session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below...

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Registeration WHERE TeamName  = @TeamName", sqlcon);

myCommand.Parameters.Add("@TeamName", TeamN)

Comment: Thanks, that worked but I had to put it as  

myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamName", TeamN);

Comment: Yes, I changed that too

Comment: @TommyK123, please select as answered.